# Request method 'GET' not supported in AWS server Spring Boot REST API status 500

Tags: java, spring, rest, amazon-ec2, postman

my Rest API is working fine locally but the moment I put the same JAR and run it from cloud server, I can only call the GET API and none of the POST API from Postmen.

Below are my code.

**RestController**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController {

@GetMapping("/all")
public String allAccess() {
    return "Public Content.";
}

@PostMapping("/testpostA")
public ResponseEntity<?> testPostA() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("Test POST successfully!"));
}

@PostMapping("/testpostB")
public String testPostB() {
    return "String return POST successfully.";
}
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.eurogain</groupId>
<artifactId>WebPortal</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>WebPortal</name>
<description>Java Spring Boot project for the Eurogain web portal for both internal and external client.</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>15</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build></project>
```

**WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    // securedEnabled = true,
    // jsr250Enabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

@Bean
public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("============================ Inside WebSecurityConfig ===========================Ken");
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
}}
```

**Lastly, the web application:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebPortalApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebPortalApplication.class, args);
}}
```

Running the same JAR file locally, no issue on calling all of the POST and GET API. However, when we move the same JAR over to AWS EC2 cloud instance and run it, we can only call the GET API. The following error was thrown at the Postmen console when calling any of the POST API:

[image: Error at the Postmen upon calling the POST method]

However, no issue when calling the GET API:
[image: No error at the Postmen upon calling the GET method]

Server console output - no error:
[image]

**UPDATE - Round 1**

Tested using **wget**, error 500 as well. No futher info.

[image]

**UPDATE - Round 2**
Tested using wget POST, and after modifying WebSecurityConfig. Here is the screeshot:

[image]

Server console contains warning upon the wget POST:

[image]

The updated code for WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
}
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use curl or wget?

Comment: @tgdavies same. Let me update the above on my test result using other tool.

Comment: wget will use GET by default. You'll need to tell it to use a POST.

Comment: @tgdavies, Ok, updated. As i was updating the code, removing all business logic, now POST return error 405. Refer the updated content above for the result of wget with POST and area that I updated.

Comment: @tgdavies please refer to the latest and updated details above - "Update - Round 2". Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an API gateway in front of your service? Perhaps that's misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

Try config cors like that:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the Nginx reverse proxy handling. In localhost, I was using HTTP, but in the dev server, we are only using HTTPS. Thus, I used HTTPS for all the RESTful API URLs.